# Producing Video Lectures

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation

What are all the software and hardware needed to produce a video of this kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like she used a graphics drawing pen tablet (e.g. a [Wacom Pen Tablet](http://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-tablets)) and recorded her screen with a screencapture software such as [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/). To have the person appear in the lower right like this, you will need a well-lit [greenscreen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key) to key out the background. To produce the video from your recordings, you will need [NLE software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_editing_software). Since there aren't any special effects in this video, you don't need a professional program; the only requirement would be the greenscreen processing capability.

Alternatively, you could also create the screen writing effects completely digitally with an animation/SFX program like [After Effects](http://www.adobe.com/products/aftereffects.html). However, this is pretty difficult and it will certainly take some time to learn the required skills to produce a video like this.